# BingMapsDirectionsTask equivalent for Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8

all is in the title, I'm looking for an equivalent in Windows 8 of the BingMapsDirectionsTask that exists in Windows Phone 7.
My purpose is to display a route without using the bing maps API.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Bing is not built in, you need to manually access a Bing or Google API to manually get directions or whatever your use is.

[Bing Map API](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx)

[Google Map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/)